# Rails - undefined method `each' for 0:Fixnum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I get the following error in Ruby on Rails `undefined method 'each' for 0:Fixnum`.

Here is the application trace :

```
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:23:in `new'
app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:23:in `create'
```

And my controller create and new actions :

```
  def new
    @video = Video.new
  end

  def create
    method = 'get_' + params[:video][:provider] + '_video_id'
    params[:video][:provider_video_id] = Video.send(method, params[:video][:url])
    params[:video][:thumb] = Video.get_thumb_from_youtube(params[:video][:provider_video_id])
    params[:video][:views] = params[:video][:likes] = 0    
    params[:video][:user_id] = current_user
    @video = Video.new(params[:video])
    if @video.save
      redirect_to video_path(@video), notice:'Video added successfully.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Here is my view.html.haml :

```
= form_for @video do |f|
 - if @video.errors.any?
  .error_explanation
    %h2= pluralize(@video.errors.count, "error")
    prohibited this user from being saved:

    %ul
      - @video.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
.field
  = f.label :title
  = f.text_field :title
.field
  = f.label :description
  = f.text_area :description
%br
.field
  = f.label :url, 'URL'
  = f.text_field :url
%br
.field
  Provider
  = radio_button :video, :provider, 'vimeo'
  = f.label :provider, 'Vimeo', :value => 'vimeo'
  = radio_button :video, :provider, 'youtube' 
  = f.label :provider, 'Youtube', :value => 'youtube'
%br
.field
  Category
  = collection_select(:video, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true)
%br
.actions
  = f.submit "Add video"
```

Comment: error seems to be in 'new.html.*' view you are rendering, pls add that code....

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace? Could you mark the lines in your files?

Comment: @Tass The line 23 is this line `@video = Video.new(params[:video])`. I replaced this line `params[:video][:views] = params[:video][:likes] = 0` with this one : `params[:video][:views] = 0` and it now works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

```
params[:video][:views] = params[:video][:likes] = 0
```

to

```
params[:video][:views] = 0
```

I assume that `video.likes` is an association, not a count, so it expects an `Enumerable`. If it's an association, rails tries to assign the elements you add to `likes` to your `video` model. The first step of adding them is to iterate - using `each`. That's where the error comes from.

Comment: I could not understand the problem so I went to work to free my mind. I'm here your answer similar to yours popped in my head! At first, I created a column like for video. Then i created another model like to manage user likes (users can only vote once) but forget to remove the Video likes column! The error can from what you explained! Thanks :)